# How can I put a second author exactly under my name?

Tags: titles

Is it even possible to do it? Is there any package that does that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what are you authoring? Please give us the minimal code. Emphasis on the minimalness but still compilable.

Comment: Please give us a minimum working example.  Without seeing anything, the best I can suggest is `\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr}` in the preamble, and `\Longstack[l]{author1\cr author2}` in the text.  But again, this depends on the particulars of your use case.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any details, but you could simply use `\\` in the author field:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\author{
  Your Name \\
  Second Name
}
\title{The example}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you'd like more vertical space, you can increase it like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\author{
  Your Name \\[6pt]
  Second Name
}
\title{The example}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: But be warned that such formatting commands in the argument of `\author` can cause problems. For example if they are automatically reused in hyperref attributes.